# Accessing h2-browser and debugging in play framework application

Tags: playframework-2.0

In play it is possible to access the h2-browser by entering the activator console and entering h2-browser.  This will bring up a web interface to the h2 in memory database.  Per the documentation, in order to debug an application you don't enter the activator console but instead run the command

```
activator -jvm-debug 9999 run
```

but I can't figure out a way to access the database after running this command.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you start the console with *h2-browser* command then it runs until you *exit* from activator. Like this:

```
activator -jvm-debug 9999 h2-browser run
```

Comment: This doesn't work but only because of the equals sign after -jvm-debug.  Edit it and I'll mark it as the answer.  I could have sworn I tried this and it didn't work but I must have made a mistake.  Thanks!

Comment: I have removed =. Thanks